# Solution to algorithm problem has slightly incorrect output. What's wrong?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

The problem was taken from [here](https://www.algoexpert.io/questions/River%20Sizes)

**Description:**
*You are given a two-dimensional array (matrix) of potentially unequal height and width containing only 0s and 1s. Each 0 represents land, and each 1 represents part of a river. A river consists of any number of 1s that are either horizontally or vertically adjacent (but not diagonally adjacent). The number of adjacent 1s forming a river determine its size. Write a function that returns an array of the sizes of all rivers represented in the input matrix. Note that these sizes do not need to be in any particular order.*

```
Sample input:
[  
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],  
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],  
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],  
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],  
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],  
]  
Sample output:  
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 5]
```

**My solution:**

I tried to solve this problem using Depth-First-Search recursively.

```
import java.util.*;
class River{
    int size;
    int[][]matrix;
    River(int[][]mat){
        matrix=mat;
    }
    void traverse(int x,int y){
        System.out.println(x+","+y);
        if((y-1)>=matrix.length && matrix[x][y-1]==1){
            size++;
            matrix[x][y-1]=0;
            traverse(x,y-1);
        } if((x+1)<matrix[0].length && matrix[x+1][y]==1){
            size++;
            matrix[x+1][y]=0;
            traverse(x+1,y);
        }if((x-1)>=matrix[0].length && matrix[x-1][y]==1){
                size++;
                matrix[x-1][y]=0;
                traverse(x-1,y);
        } 
        if((y+1)<matrix.length && matrix[x][y+1]==1){
            size++;
            matrix[x][y+1]=0;
            traverse(x,y+1);
        }
    }
}
class Program {
  public static List<Integer> riverSizes(int[][] matrix) {
        List<Integer> SList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<River> RList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Traversal:");

        for(int i=0;i<matrix[0].length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<matrix.length;j++){
                if(matrix[i][j]==1){
                    matrix[i][j]=0;
                    River river = new River(matrix);
                    river.size++;
                    river.traverse(i,j);
                    RList.add(river);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sizes:");
        for(River r:RList){
            SList.add(r.size);
            System.out.println(r.size);
        }
    return SList;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[][]riverM={
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };

        System.out.println("("+riverM.length+","+riverM[0].length+")");
        riverSizes(riverM);
    }
}
```

My output passed 7/12 cases. This is one of the case that went wrong.

**My Output:**

```
Sizes:
1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Sizes:
1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,
```

Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: What is the input for that case? And please describe the problem you are solving, not just with a link.

Comment: @kaya3 I assume the input is in the code, in the main method.

Comment: @kaya3 Added the description. Input is in the main method.

Comment: The problem seams to be the branching river (7). I suggest you create a mini-exmaple with such a branching river and check if your implementation fails. If *yes* start debugging to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Non-square matrices go wrong too, it is `matrix[y][x], y < matrix.length, x < matrix[0].length`.

Comment: Ok, now that you have a working solution, try doing it without editing the matrix in place. Meaning, after the method returns, the matrix should remain intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is located into your `traverse` function:

```
if((y-1)>=matrix.length && matrix[x][y-1]==1){...}
```

The left part of the condition `(y-1)>=matrix.length` is wrong. Here, correct me if I'm wrong, you just want to prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. To do it, you should test something like `(y-1) >= 0`.

Same error when you're testing your `x` index. Test the output with these fixes, didn't check if there's something else wrong.

Comment: Yup ```(y-1) >= 0``` worked. I don't know how I didn't see this.